# Для чего в ASP.NET используется в качестве id GUID?

Tags: asp.net

Для чего в ASP.NET используется в качестве id GUID?

Почему он так странно выглядит da047c2b-3be1-45f4-b240-ab945ce4991e
?

Не проще было бы использовать просто цифры или буквы без тире? Какие приемущества?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Его главная особенность — уникальность, которая позволяет создавать расширяемые сервисы и приложения без опасения конфликтов, вызванных совпадением идентификаторов. Иными словами сгенирировать два одинаковых значения GUID очень-очень-очень мала.

В ASP.Net можно использовать и int-овый Id. Все зависит от поставленной задачи.

https://habrahabr.ru/post/265437/